# How to access to sharepoint files in VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, office365

I'm develloping some applications for managing my team and we are facing to access to sharepoint file in which I want to find if a file exist or not. Code is a below

```
Rep = "https://technip.sharepoint.com/sites/LoadingSystems-Projectmanagement/Shared Documents/Monthly 
project review sheets/"
Rep1 = Rep
Rep = Replace(Replace(Rep, "https:", ""), "/", "\")
Rep = Replace(Rep, Split(Rep, "\")(2), Split(Rep, "\")(2) & "@SSL")
i = 0

Fichier = Dir(Rep, vbDirectory)
```

As a first approach we thought that it was due to the fact that users were not connected to their Microsoft office 365 account, but sometimes they are and problem still appears. Any idea to get around this barrier and be able to access to that Sharepoint folder for a search at every time?? "Rep is declared as a string", maybe it's wrong I'm not a VBA expert just a Project Manager which try to develop small apps for his team.

Thanks for your support !

Loïc

Comment: The above code only works (maybe) if the SharePoint site is mapped to the UNC path you are using. Are you sure this is the case for every user who executes the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't be work for SharePoint Online.

You can use:

- [CLI for Microsoft 365](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/)
- [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) via Office add-ins (word, excel, outlook), or other ways and apps
- [MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)